# docker-compose only mount files that exist on host to container

Tags: docker, permissions, docker-compose

Is it possible to to mount a host directory in to a container but only allowing overwriting files that exist on the host?

Example github repo: https://github.com/UniBen/stackoverflow-59031249

E.g
Host:

```
src/
  public/
    index.php (200kb)
```

Container:

```
src/
  public/
    index.php (100kb)
  vendor/
  ...
```

Desired output: (The container file system merged with the mounted host system files which exists. Note the size of the index.php file.)

```
src/
  public/
    index.php (200kb)
  vendor/
  ...
```

Actual output:

```
src/
  public/
    index.php (200kb)
```

Example docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.2'

services:
    php:
      image: php
      volumes:
        - ./src:/src
```

Edit: So it looks like overlayfs implemented by docker is only used for bulding docker images and can not be used for volumes what so ever. I still think it's possible to specify a custom driver but not sure how. As a temp fix I've done some fancy stuff with mapping stuff out of container, diffing it and putting it back in but not ideal.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the "desired output" vs "actual output" examples: from what perspective are those file listings? The host? The container?

Comment: @larsks Yes. Essentially, I want to keep the vendor folder as is because it doesn't exist in the host therefore shouldn't overwrite but the index.php should be overwritten because it exists on the host.

Comment: To be clear I'm not sure docker/docker-compose has this functionality. Wonder if there's a funky file driver that implements this kind of functionality.

Comment: Do you need to disabling copying when a volume is created?

Comment: @funnydman I'll give this ago.

Comment: @funnydman Sadly this doesn't work. The container /src directory is completely overwritten by the hosts src dir. The desired functionality is basically a merge of the two file systems, not a straight overwrite which is currently what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to to mount a host directory in to a container but ...

No.  The only Docker mounting option is a straight-up "replace this directory in the container with the equivalent directory from the host".  There is no way to modify this, selectively hide subdirectories, or implement your "only if it already exists" rule.

In the example you're showing, you probably don't want a volume at all.  Files like `index.php` and a `vendor` directory are application source code, and in typical use you'd write a Dockerfile, `COPY index.php .` to move the file into the image, and then `RUN composer ...` to create the vendor tree.  This would be isolated from your host environment, so the `vendor` directory in the image would be separate from whatever existed on your host system.

Comment: Thanks, thought this might be the case. Just to note, If I were running this as a prod container I would do `RUN composer ...' however, the reason why I wanted to only mount files that are on the host without individually mounting them in volumes is so for development purposes. A volume is absolutely necessary for a dev environment so my changes can be reflected immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there are no options to control such behavior, e.g, how data between source and dest will be handled. But if David's answer is not really your case you could do something like this:

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  example:
    build:
      context: .
    volumes:
      - data:/src
      - ./src:/src/host

volumes:
  data:
```

How docker [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#populate-a-volume-using-a-container) says:

> If you start a container which creates a new volume, and the container
>   has files or directories in the directory to be mounted the
>   directory’s contents are copied into the volume.

So after that, let's investigate a little bit:

```
/src # ls
file.a.txt  file.c.txt  host

/src # cat host/file.a.txt 
host

/src # cat file.a.txt 
container
/src # cat file.c.txt 
container
```

Data from from container is saved into `data` named volume. The data from the host machine live in the host folder. Now you can copy from the host folder to the `src` with `cp` or `rsync` with any rules that you want.

This is a quite fishy and artificial example, maybe it's a good idea to rethink current implementation.

Comment: Thanks. I'm currently investigating unionfs which docker already implements for building layers.
More here: https://www.terriblecode.com/blog/how-docker-images-work-union-file-systems-for-dummies/